# Assignment operator overloads have similar conversions (only in VS)

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, using-declaration

I have a class hierarchy with three classes (A, B and C). A and B are base-classes, parametrized with the derived Type. Class C is derived from both, A and B.

The class B provides an assignment operator for objects of type A and class C inherits this assignment operator with the `using super::operator=` declaration.

When I define a constructor in class B from objects of type A, I get the **Error:** *two overloads have similar conversions* (C2666) in Visual Studio 2013, but I don't get any error, or warning in gcc (4.8.2), clang (3.4) and intel icc (Studio 2015). (compiled with `-Wall -pedantic`)

Here the reduced example:

```
template <class Model> struct A {};

template <class Model> struct B
{
    B() {}; // default constructor

    // copy constructor for objects of type A
    template <class M> 
    B(A<M> const&) {} 

    // assignment operator for objects of type A
    template <class M>
    Model& operator=(A<M> const& rhs)
    {
        return static_cast<Model&>(*this);
    }
};

struct C : public B<C>, public A<C>
{
    typedef B<C>  super;

    // copy assignment operator
    C& operator=(C const& rhs) { return *this; }

    // adopt assignment operator for A<C> from super-class
    using super::operator=;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A<C> a;
    c = a;
}
```

If I would replace the templated class A by a non-templated class it also compiles in Visual Studio without errors - but this is not the way it could be solved.

**My question is**: is this construct well-formed in the sense that it is standard conform, or is the error-message correct? Does a specifier like `explicit` for the copy constructor in B helps to solve the problem?

By the way: In Visual Studio, I get the **Warning**: *multiple assignment operators specified* (C4522), because of the copy assignment operator in class C. Can somebody exmplain to me, why this should be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC and CLANG are correct and MSVC is wrong:

## What's the expected behaviour:

The statement `c=a;` uses the `operator=`  that you've defined in `B`,  because an `A<C>` is not necessarily a `C`.  So let's write down the the declaration of `operator=` of `B<C>` by manually doing the type substitution:

```
template <class M> 
C& operator=(A<M> const& rhs)
```

As `a` is a `A<C>`, the obvious implicit instantiation candidate of this template would be:

```
 C& operator=(A<C> const& rhs)
```

This is in fact the only possible instantiation (you could verify that GCC uses it by displaying the typeinfo).

## What is MSVC trying to do ?

If you'd change simplify the class C to an even more minimalistic form, you'd still get the[error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyafzty4.aspx):

```
struct C : public B<C>   // single inheritance
{   using B<C>::operator=; };  // nothing else
```

In fact the problem is caused by the constructor `B(A<M> const&)` :

- comment it out, and the code will compile
- **make it explicit** and the code will also compmile

MSVC identifies wrongly a second potental candidate for the member function's implicit specialisation.  As this constructor allows to convert implicitely from  `A<M>` to `B<C>`, the candidate is:

```
 C& operator=(B<C> const& rhs)
```

But according to the C++ standard, this shouldn't be envisaged by the compiler at all:

> **14.8.1/6:** Implicit conversions  will be performed on a function argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function
> parameter **if the parameter type contains no template-parameters**
> that participate in template argument deduction.

So this is clearly a bug of MSVC.

**By the way:**

The warning about multiple assignemnt operators is [just an information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd45k287.aspx). Apparently MS assumes that this might be a frequent cause for mistakes.  And now to the core question...